# Object and array exception

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, doctype

I have a problem with `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`.  The program throws the following exception.

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

I've read a lot of solutions, but I can't find any for my code:

```java
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Connection.SHOW_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_URL, new Response.Listener< JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String nrorder = object.getString("nrorder").trim();
                String nrarticle = object.getString("nrarticle").trim();

                Orders orders = new Orders();
                orders.setNrorder(nrorder);
                orders.setNrarticle(nrarticle);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Php Code:

```
require_once 'config.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$orders = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $index['nrorder'] = $row['nrorder'];
    $index['nrarticle'] = $row['nrarticle'];
    array_push($orders, $index);
}

echo json_encode($orders);
```

Config.php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'loginregister');
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
echo '';
```

Comment: Your problem is that your service at Connection.SHOW_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_URL isn't returning a JSON array. In fact it's not returning JSON at all but probably HTML. This might be some kind of error response.

Comment: I deleted doctype from my orders.php and i have the same problem bez without doctype -.- below code from my php script: `<?php

 require_once 'config.php';

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $orders = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $index['nrorder'] = $row['nrorder'];
    $index['nrarticle'] = $row['nrarticle']; array_push($orders, $index);
 }

 echo json_encode($orders);

?> `

Comment: Please look at the output of your PHP page. Also if your error message has changed, update your question.